# ember where to put jquery ready-function?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i have a problem getting Ember into an existing website-template.

Some visual effects of the website are javascript-based and have to be initialized.
The static html-version of the web-design uses the a script-tag with the following code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    Main.init();
});
```

In case loading the website direct to a route (e.g. call localhost:9000/#/content/web) the visual-effects do not work.
If i load the page to its root (where i don't have defined content to be shown by ember yet) everything is okay (even if i click on a link-to /content/web, the content is shown correctly).

Cause the init-script is placed at the pages end, i guess the content which is shown through ember-logic prevent its execution.

Does anyone know how to place such init-sequences the right way with ember?

Comment: you may once have a look on `didInsertElement` hook in View class..i think that will work like you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Like @CodeJack mentioned you should probably Create a view and override the 'didInsertElement' hook. Jquery pluging should be wrapped in views. It makes it easier to cleanup the plugin when the view is removed.

That said, ember js does have a **[ready](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#event_ready)** event that is fired once the dom is ready.
You can use it like

```
Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    //do ur initialization.
  }
});
```

Comment: Dear @blessenm, where to put this code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402054/ember-personal-generic-javascript-code-where-to-put-application-component

Comment: @JohnSam I havent worked with ember in a really long time. But I think there is app.js or application.js generated by ember-cli and this code would go there. But I would recommend just using components. If you want to initialize something in app startup, create a root component in the application template file and do all ur initial setup in the component. I wish I could be more specific but my ember knowledge is outdated.